# How do I change the cursor to a line in an OpenGL window?

Tags: opengl

I want to have a red line instead of mouse pointer in my (written in C++ with OpenGL) application.  For example when I move the mouse over an OpenGL window, I would like the cursor to become a red line.  How can I do that?

Also, how can I call the  mouse related functions (OpenGL) for that line and specify the functionality?

Comment: There are no OpenGL "mouse related functions". OpenGL doesn't acknowledge what a mouse is. OpenGL barely acknowledges what a _window_ is.

Comment: Yep.  This will be specific to your windowing library.  Are you using something like SDL?  GLUT?

Answer (score 0):

As Nicol Bolas said in his comment, OpenGL knows nothing of the mouse.   You'll need to interact with the windowing system one way or another (via direct Win32/X11/etc. API or via a portable windowing library a la Qt, wxWidgets, etc) to monitor mouse position.

If the cursor you're trying to draw is a bitmap, your best bet is likely to handle mouse enter/leave events sent to your window and respond to them by using an API function to change the cursor.  This will handle automatically updating the cursor as the mouse moves around and will add minimal overhead to your application (windowing system cursors generally draw in an overlay plane that avoids sending redraw events to your window every time the mouse moves).

If you have a more procedural description of your cursor (that is, you intend to draw it with OpenGL drawing commands), you'll instead want to handle the mouse enter/leave events by using `HideCursor()/ShowCursor()` commands or the equivalent to turn off the windowing system's native cursor when the mouse is over your window.  Then, you'll hook the mouse move callbacks and redraw your scene, adding whatever commands you need to draw the cursor at the position specified in the mouse move event.

The first approach is definitely preferred for performance & latency reasons--but there are some cursor types (think full screen crosshairs) that can't be accomodated that way.